# Parse JavasScript update line in User table

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I try to update a line in "User" table and I can't.
(If I try to update a line in another table it is work!.)
My code:

```
var query331 = new Parse.Query("User");
        query331.find({
          success: function(results3) {
          for (var i = 0; i < results3.length; i++) { 
            var object31 = results3[i];
            object31.set("Updates",true);
            object31.save();
            }
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Parse User class is special class that you can query via the below query construction;

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
```

Also, if you are dealing with a unique user you can use the getFirst method.One suggestion for operation like updates more than 1 record you can use Parse saveAll method. Hope this helps.

Regards.